# Tapestry Templates from database or modify at runtime

Tags: java, tapestry

Is it possible to load Tapestry templates from a database or an alternative source?
I have a requirement to modify the templates at rumtime. What is the best strategy for something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a dynamic templating component that is moving from the tapx component library to core Tapestry in 5.3. It appears to let you use external resources in place of components with some support for expansion similar to tml files. [Here is a brief description of it.](http://tapestryjava.blogspot.com/2010/05/tapestry-happenings-52-beta-soon-new.html) The docs haven't been updated yet, but you can see the source directly [here](https://github.com/apache/tapestry5/blob/release-5.3.0/tapestry-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Dynamic.java).